# After declaring an array, all elements somehow become the last element

Tags: c++, arrays

Basically, I'm building some code in which an array of objects (I've made the object myself) need to be accessible class wide, but initialized after some other steps. This is what I've made:

---

#### The base object

```
unsigned char stepPin;
unsigned char dirPin;
unsigned char sensorPin;
const char* ident;

//Object
StepperMotor :: StepperMotor(const unsigned char _stepPin,
            const unsigned char _dirPin, 
            const unsigned char _sensorPin, 
            const char* _ident)
{
    stepPin = _stepPin;
    dirPin = _dirPin;
    sensorPin = _sensorPin;
    ident = _ident;
    std::cout << "Motor " << ident << ": Step Pin - " << (int)stepPin << " | Direction Pin - " << (int)dirPin << std::endl;
}
```

---

#### The object manager

```
#include "stepperMotor.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include "stepperManager.h"

StepperMotor motors[] = { 
    {7, 15, 16, "HS"},
    {0, 1, 2, "HL"},
    {3, 4, 5, "HP"},
    {12, 13, 6, "CS"},
    {14, 10, 11, "VP"},
    {21, 22, 26, "TC"},
    {23, 24, 27, "TR"},
    {25, 28, 29, "IN"}
};

StepperManager::StepperManager()
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        motors[i].dumpData();
    }
}
```

---

#### Now to the actual problem...

After the initial declaration, all the elements in the array become the last element. You can see this by looking at the output when it's run:

Output:

```
Motor HS: Step Pin - 7 | Direction Pin - 15
Motor HL: Step Pin - 0 | Direction Pin - 1
Motor HP: Step Pin - 3 | Direction Pin - 4
Motor CS: Step Pin - 12 | Direction Pin - 13
Motor VP: Step Pin - 14 | Direction Pin - 10
Motor TC: Step Pin - 21 | Direction Pin - 22
Motor TR: Step Pin - 23 | Direction Pin - 24
Motor IN: Step Pin - 25 | Direction Pin - 28
Declare the motor man
Motor IN: Step Pin - 25 | Direction Pin - 28
Motor IN: Step Pin - 25 | Direction Pin - 28
Motor IN: Step Pin - 25 | Direction Pin - 28
Motor IN: Step Pin - 25 | Direction Pin - 28
Motor IN: Step Pin - 25 | Direction Pin - 28
Motor IN: Step Pin - 25 | Direction Pin - 28
Motor IN: Step Pin - 25 | Direction Pin - 28
Motor IN: Step Pin - 25 | Direction Pin - 28
```

So, I don't fully understand why this is happening, I've tried making the array static, and switching to vectors instead, but none of it has helped. I'm afraid that I just don't know enough about the language to find the issue on my own.

---

#### EDIT

It was pointed out that I missed the actual run code. Sorry about that guys.

This is the "main" file that implements the objects.

```
#include <iostream>               // For cout and cerr
#include <cstdlib>                // For atoi()
#include <cstring>
#include "stepperManager.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::cout << "Declare the motor man" << std::endl;
    StepperManager motorMan;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What prints `Declare the motor man`?

Comment: That output is not coming from any code you have shown. How can we answer your question?

Comment: I don't think there's enough here for anybody to solve your problem. But I'll give you one general tip: prefer [standard container classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) to arrays in C++.

Comment: Yes, the code you're showing doesn't match the output whatsoever. We have no idea what is going on if the code during which your data gets screwed up isn't shown that actually writes to `motors`. It might also be a bit premature to be involving threads here until you get the hang of the language and how to use the debugger.

Comment: Sorry, I've added the main code. I forgot it.

Comment: You are still not showing all of the output lines (e.g. we don't see "Initialize the GPIO"). But in your constructor, you call `init` on each, and I don't see what that even does (it calls code you don't show).

Comment: @Hollish You need to be using member variables here for `StepperMotor`. Every time you initialize one of those, you're writing to global file-scope variables, so you're just overwriting the same data with each `StepperMotor` you construct. That's why all of the motors have the same values -- they're sharing the same variables/state. It's somewhat like using static variables in C# -- here you want non-static member variables.

Comment: @crashmstr The issue is present prior to either of those calls, I didn't see how it would be relevant. Not to mention I felt it would detract form the universality of the issue.

Comment: @Hollish How am I supposed to know that is present prior to either of those calls? And if that is the case, then most of your main is irrelevant and should be removed and reduced to a *minimal* example that replicates the problem.

Comment: @Ike I think I get what you're saying, but I'm not sure how to implement that here. As I understand it, the variables should be non-static already. Could you please point me to an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you want to learn a bit more about classes and how they work. In `StepperMotor's` source file, you're defining file-scope global variables with external linkage. Every time you construct a `StepperMotor`, you're overwriting those same variables, so all `StepperMotors` are effectively accessing the same values (and hence the behavior you're seeing).

Since you have a C# background, it's like you're using static member variables for `StepperMotors` here. You want non-static member variables. Simple example:

Foo.h:

```
// Foo.h
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class Foo
{
public:
    explicit Foo(int value);
    void print_value() const;

private:
    int member_variable;
}

#endif
```

Foo.cpp:

```
// Foo.cpp
#include "Foo.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Foo::Foo(int value): member_variable(value)
{
}

void Foo::print_value() const
{
     cout << member_variable << endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
// main.cpp
#include "Foo.h"

int main()
{
    Foo f1(123);
    Foo f2(456);
    Foo f3(789);
    f1.print_value();
    f2.print_value();
    f3.print_value();
}
```

Output:

```
123
456
789
```

Also I see some thread usage in your example. I'd suggest, at this point, that this is like juggling razor blades. You want to kind of stick to the basics first, get the hang of the language, debugger, and then you can babystep your way towards parallelizing execution, micro-tuning with a profiler in hand, etc.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the explanation! I had seen declaration of variables in the header file, but I didn't quite get why. Thanks again, it works now!

Answer (score 0):

You've declared four global variables, which you change every time a `StepperMotor` is created. Instead, you want these to be class members, so that each object has its own copy of them, independent of those in other objects:

```
class StepperMotor {
    unsigned char stepPin;
    unsigned char dirPin;
    unsigned char sensorPin;
    const char* ident;

    // and constructors, member functions, etc.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be something like this in your steppermotor.h

```
class StepperMotor{

//some more stuff

public:
  unsigned char stepPin;
  unsigned char dirPin;
  unsigned char sensorPin;
  const char* ident;
  unsigned int stepVal;
}
```

This is how member variables are declared in c++. 
I think it might be usefull though to read some c++ tutorial, to learn the basics.

Comment: Very true, thank you for pointing this out. I had some understanding that variables could be declared this way, but didn't fully realize why. Thank you very much.